# Switch background service to foreground when the app quits

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

- In my App, I started the background service for doing api cal for every 30 seconds. I started with START_STICKY. When android stops the service , sometimes its not getting restart.

So i want run the foreground service by showing notification when user close the application. if i re-open the app, i have to stop the foreground service and start the background service.

How to implement this? Any help *

Comment: please define "when user close the application"

Comment: user swipe from recent app